# Can you identify this ship of 1922?

Tags: 20th-century, transportation

I would like to identify the ship name and origin (from this [link](http://neareastmuseum.com/archives/?search_query=beirut&wpas=1))

[image]

Addtional info with picture -
Caption: Children evacuated from the interior by boat arriving in Beirut
Year Created: 1922
Source: Near East Foundation archives

Comment: You need to add something to the question, to tell us what's going on and why you think it's happening in 1922.

Comment: Given the photo caption (i.e. arriving from the interior by boat) it's possible that the ship in the background may be unrelated to the foreground subjects.

Comment: It is just me or the ship seems to be off-balance? As if she had hit the ground or was partially flooded?

Comment: The same picture is at https://www.flickr.com/photos/mennonitechurchusa-archives/14000328767/in/faves-40932353@N08/ and if the children came to Beirut via Caesarea then I would guess it could be quite possible that they came by boat along the coast

Comment: Same ship appears in [articles](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.levantineheritage.com/i/fire80.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.levantineheritage.com/fire.htm&h=446&w=700&tbnid=QxdzWBCj9AfV6M&tbnh=179&tbnw=281&usg=__DwFvZW3Mct-3-F_WELIAALbzSls=&docid=uDrjFI0MkZ1GvM) concerning Smyrna fire of 1922, which coincides with timeline mentioned.

Comment: The funnel colours do not obviously match anything in this (1912) book of shipping line markings, suggesting either a company founded postwar, or a very minor one - http://research.mysticseaport.org/item/l011061/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not find any direct information on the ship, but did find another image of what appears to be the same ship, present on another [web page](http://www.levantineheritage.com/fire.htm) describing operations of the [Near East Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_East_Foundation) group in 1922, this time at [the fire at Smyrna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_fire_of_Smyrna).[image]

After linking the ship to the Near East Relief efforts, reading some of the early accounts of the events of the time led to this passage from [The Interior, Volume 53](https://books.google.com/books?id=e3ZPAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA1534&lpg=PA1534&dq=near%20east%20relief%20chartered%20steamships%201922&source=bl&ots=uLVEMskgcR&sig=FY4HP9ntLRoIw7uafgWUKLytbFo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1tZD8qarRAhVGy2MKHXLZBjAQ6AEIKjAC#v=onepage&q&f=false), dated November 30 1922:

> One such message from Athens reads as follows The evacuation of all
>   Asia Minor orphans is necessary All Greek children are already enroute
>   The Armenians are following immediately The steamship *Belgravian* chartered by
>   Near East Relief is evacuating from Samsoun direct to Greece Steamship
>   *Marta* is proceeding with Syrian and Nestorian refugees from Constantinople to Mosul via Alexandretta ***Marta*** will then proceed to Mersine to
>   **evacuate 3,000 orphans from that port to Beirut** We are establishing a skeleton organization in Greece to make arrangements the orphans The
>   steamship *Marie Louise* is evacuating the remainder of the Kouleli
>   boys also Constantinople orphans located on the Asiatic side or in
>   requisitioned buildings...

So I believe the ship in question may have been the **Marta**, according to the records concerning the relief operations at the time. Unfortunately I haven't any more info on the Marta, yet.